# Can I repair Windows 7 with a different Windows 7 CD,for correction of restoring,without alternating main features of Windows?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I can't restore my computer to its original condition. It gives the error:

> The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible 0xc000000e

Can I repair my Windows 7 (home premium,2009,service pack 1) with a different Windows 7 CD that is cracked, without alternating main features of Windows for example updating windows. I mean that whether Windows preserves its features or changes them to thats of the repair windows CD?

Comment: More details please! Which windows version do you have installed, what kind of DVD do you have access too, ... Windows 7 only got "startup repair", there is no possibility doing a "repair installation" as available in XP.

Comment: Please explain what you really want to do, why you want to do it, and what you mean by "alternating main features".

Comment: What main features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like some boot loader issues. Use the [startup repair assistant](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html) contained on every windows installation disk to repair your bootloader. This should work with every Windows 7 DVD as it does only recreate your boot loader and does not touch your windows installation itself. You will be able to exchange all different windows versions (eg. Home Premium, Business, ...), but not 32 and 64 bits!

I do not recommend using cracked windows DVDs as you cannot know if there is some integrated malware. Sure you know somebody who's using the same OS version you do and got an installation disk with his computer?